# Log4j2 customize file path with rollingFileAppender (Java)

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I am migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j2 in my spring boot application. Being on log4j 1.x I used to define the properties as follows:

```
log4j.appender.A1=package.CustomRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=<base.path>/company/logs/main.log
```

in my CustomRollingFileAppender I would extend this class with the DailyRollingFileAppender, and would override the setName() method to change my '<base.path>' to the relevant directory name.

Migrating to log4j 2.x I no longer have the class DailyRollingFileAppender and can't extend RollingFileAppender because it is declared as a final. I can't override the writeToName function either.

So, how do I go about changing the <base.path> in my properties file to the relevant directory name based on my environment static properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically do not touch the implementation code of log4j2 classes. What you're trying to do can be done through [configuration](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-rollingfileappender-example/).

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

You can do what you're asking like this

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${BASE_DIR}/application.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${BASE_DIR}/application.%d{dd-MMM}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
logger.rolling.name = rollingFile
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

where `BASE_DIR` is an environment variable

Comment: This was really helpful, Thank you.